# Inno Setup - Auto download latest setup from Sourceforge and install

Tags: inno-setup, inno-tools-downloader

I'm a beginner. I have a Project that requires a third party open sourced software to function. Using Inno Setup,

1. **Which of the following is the best way to trigger that 3rd party setup?**

   - Option A: Display a custom page at the end and ask if user wants to auto open browser and download the setup
   - Option B: Ask if user would like to install the setup in a custom page before setup. Download the software and open setup after installation.
2. **How to download latest setup from Sourceforge and install after installation?** Because `http://sourceforge.net/projects/xxx/files/latest/download?source=files` is an HTML page and it only triggers the download after a few secs. I cannot just download the URL using Innotools Downloader.

Comment: 1. there is no best option. It's entirely upon you to decide. 2. that download is just a redirect. You don't need to wait for it, simply copy [`the direct link`](http://i.imgur.com/VIpKTZO.png).

Comment: @TLama but the direct link is not always the latest version! :( I don't think anyone would want to install an old version if there is a new one.

Comment: Oh, that's right, it depends on the project. The *smarter* ones are using version-less files to download. Well, then I'm out of ideas as it's not an ordinary URL redirection, but a JavaScript that makes you redirect after a while. That's what no downloader plugin (without HTML/JavaScript support) can do.

Comment: @TLama I'm already thinking way too complicated. Using web technology such as opening a portable node.js command line in the background and download the project using JS technology then use the `AfterInstallation` to open up the setup. Will it work or is it too complicated?

Comment: I don't know what the node.js is for, so I can't speak for it. Another clumsy option might be parsing that downloaded HTML. Though the best here would be having your own server (e.g. FTP) serving the latest version by yourself, I'd say.